# recv() always returns -1 in android

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk

I need to send few strings on localhost via socket on android using native code (in C particularity) but I've faced weird problem - recv() function always returns -1 and eerno tells "Try again!"

Here is code responsible for initialization of socket and receiving response

```
void request() {

    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //need to send string to localhost
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(sa.sin_addr));
   
    int sock;
    char res[7];
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sa.sin_port = htons(27042);
    int connection = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof sa);
    if (connection != -1) { //connection >= 0
        memset(res, 0, 7);

        send(sock, "\x00", 1, NULL);

        send(sock, "AUTH\r\n", 6, NULL);

        usleep(100); // Give it some time to answer

        int rec = recv(sock, res, 7, MSG_DONTWAIT);

        // rec is always -1 and errno says "Try again!"

    }

    close(sock);
}
```

There is an `INTERNET` permission in `Manifest` file.

I've tried to put `recv(sock, res, 7, MSG_DONTWAIT)` part in while loop to wait maybe it would return some data but no success. Maybe I need to call something like flush() after send()?

Does any one know where could be trouble?

**UPD.** This code runs in one android app (client) and tries to send string to other android app that runs on the same device (server).

Comment: `"127.0.0.1"` Where is your server running? Where is your client running? Did you post code for a server or a client?

Comment: @blackapps added UPD

Comment: "Try again!"... That's probably EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK or EINTR. The first two indicates a non-blocking handle. The last occurs under some conditions when a signal is received. If it's a non-blocking handle, the solution depends on why you made the handle non-blocking. If it's the later, just try again.

Comment: You are using the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag: "*`MSG_DONTWAIT` **Enables nonblocking operation**; if the operation would block, the call fails with the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.*" So, if there is no data to read when you call `recv()`, it is going to tell you to "Try Again". If you are expecting data to arrive, but no data ever does, then either the server is flawed, or the request you are sending to trigger data is flawed. You are sending an `AUTH` request, are you expected to send credentials with it, perhaps? Or are you expected to receive a response first? What protocol are you implementing?

Answer (score 0):

Solution became pretty obvious - current "server" version can't process "AUTH" message that is why "client" app receive -1 response. I've tried older version and everything worked fine.